# Calculating perplexity with smoothing techniques (NLP)

Tags: natural-language, language-models, laplace-smoothing, perplexity

This question is about smoothed n-gram language models. When we use additive smoothing on the train set to determine the conditional probabilities, and calculate the perplexity of train data, where exactly is this useful when it comes to the test set?

Which of these two things do we do?

1. apply the conditional probabilities calculated using smoothing in the train set to the same n-grams that we might see in the test set, then calculate the perplexity for the test set separately?
2. apply smoothing on the test set as well? If that's the case, what's
   the point of having a train set and a test set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you asked about smoothed n-gram models, your question is more general. You want to know how the computations done in a model on a training set relate to computations on the test set.

---

**Training set computations.**
You should learn the parameters of your (n-gram) model using the training set only. *In your case, the parameters are the conditional probabilities. For instance, you may find that $p(\text{cat})=\frac{7+\lambda}{1000+\lambda V}$ if your vocabulary size is $V$. These numbers are the ones you’d use to compute perplexity on the training set.*

**Test set computations.**
When you compute the perplexity of the model on the test set, you reuse the same learned parameters from before. *You don’t recompute $p(\text{cat})$. You still use $\frac{7+\lambda}{1000+\lambda V}$, regardless of how often “cat” appears in the test data. (One notable problem to beware of: if a word is not in your vocabulary but shows up in the test set, even the smoothed probability will be 0. To fix this, it’s a common practice to “UNK your data”, which you can look up separately.)*

---

**The point.**
The point of this is to see how well your model *generalizes*. The test data is a surrogate for real-world data that you’ll see when deploying your model. You ignore it when fitting the model. You then compute perplexity on the test data, as an estimate of how you’d do on that real world data.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: I will not spam you with notifications on each question, but I observed that all of the 0-credit answers you have listed on your profile have at least one up-vote. In some cases they are the accepted answer, as is the case here.

Comment: The profile doesn't get updated often enough, I guess! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Bigrams

(a) Compute the bigram count table, C(w2|w1) for the sentence "I saw Susie sitting in a shoe shine shop. Where Susie sits Susie shines, and where Susie shines Susie sits." Put w1 in the left hand column, and w2 in the top row. Include punctuation, clitics, and sentence start and end markers as individual tokens, and index words using their lemmatized forms.

(b) Compute the bigram probability table, P(w2|w1) for above sentence, assuming the following overall unigram counts: C(I)=2, C(see)= 25, C(Susie)=10, C(sit)=20, C(in)=80, C(a)=90, C(shoe)=50, C(shine) = 20, C(shop) = 20, C(Where)=60, C(,)=80, C(and)=100.  assume there are 75 senteses in the corpus, and they all end with a period.

(c) Compute the probability and perplexity of the first sentence in (a) using the bigram approximation.